# Is this a damaged passport?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, damaged-passports

Should I renew my passport? I am going to apply for a visa interview for the USA, for a masters. Would this be a problem for visa verification? [image: photo of a passport with some damage]

Comment: indian passport

Comment: No mam, according to that his stamp was little Smudged nd the corner water line is very dark. my passport is slightly yellowish and it didn't change any pattern of line

Comment: Yes, the stain on the linked page is different. However, the salient features of your passport — the cover is undamaged, the binding is intact, and the data page and photograph are not impaired. Thus, the same analysis and conclusion applies.

Comment: If you look at this page on a computer screen there is a list to the right with related questions, on a phone it is low down on the page I think, look at those that are about passport damage to see if one is more like your stain.

Comment: okay than you sir, Im applying for renewal